# Automatic Login in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, login, web-services, external

I have an **application** where the **user logs in**, and I have a **web service** where I can **send the data**.

How can I get the **user logged in automatically** to the **e-commerce** with the data received?

Comment: I think you should use [APIs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication.html) for your requirement.

Comment: when did your web service send the data to magento?